# Show surname and rest of the name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with customer names, and I want to separate the last name from the rest of the name.

In the name Diana Margarida Paulino Maria

If I use:

```
$str = "Diana Margarida Paulino Maria";

// Get Frist and Last Word
   $array = explode(" ",$str);

   $first_word = $array[0];

   $last_word  = $array[count($array)-1];

   echo $first_word. ', '.$last_word;
```

It's every thin ok, anda show Diana as first_word and Maria as last_word

```
Even is I use:

    function getLastWord($string)
    {
        $string = explode(' ', $string);
        $last_word = array_pop($string);
        return $last_word;
    }
```

Or this

```
  $words = explode( " ", $str );
array_splice( $words, -1 );
echo implode( " ", $words );
```

In this case show name without surname

The problem is that if you return a php msqyl select query from that name and use these functions, the nickname never appears

I've tried directly through the mysql query itself

```
SELECT substring_index(nome, ' ', 1) as first, substring_index(nome, ' ', -1) as last
```

And in the specific case of this name (and some others - Leandro Monteiro Rodrigues Figueiredo; Pedro António Duarte Lopes) the nickname still does not appear

I used the above codes with many other names and in almost all situations the nickname is indicated correctly

In the mysql database the name field is encoded with utf8_general_ci

Either way it's weird because I can't find a pattern for the error

Comment: You need to store it in different fields, one for the first names, and the other for the surname

Comment: _"and I want to separate the last name from the rest of the name"_ - that is really rather impossible, because you can't know which "parts" belong to the first, and which to the last name, _for certain_. At most you will be able to make an "educated guess", that will still turn out _wrong_ in some cases.

Comment: But if I use the php explode function (in while select), 95% of the time the surname appears correctly, except in the examples I mentioned

Comment: Perhaps the "space" in those values isn't an actual space - but a non-breaking space perhaps, or a different white-space character. Make a debug output of `rawurlencode` applied to the values, then you will be able to see the actual byte values in those places easily.

Comment: You're right @CBroe, I went to put the name again and it worked fine. What will happen? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You could replace all sequences of whitespace characters with a single space on insertion.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, when people entered their names they added an extra space at the end of the name.
Thanks for your help